# how to load dynamic text sharedObject when flash is reopened in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe-animate

I created a simple username page, in **frame 1**, there is a button and input text

like the code below

```
stop();
var SOlastFrame: SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("save_frame2");
var shared_data: String

next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotomyNextFrame);

function gotomyNextFrame(e: MouseEvent): void {
    shared_data = inputName.text

    nextFrame()
    SOlastFrame.data.lastframe = currentFrame;
    SOlastFrame.flush();

}

if (SOlastFrame.data.lastframe != null) {
    gotoAndStop(SOlastFrame.data.lastframe);
}
```

i saved the last frame by adding this code

```
SOlastFrame.data.lastframe = currentFrame;
SOlastFrame.flush();
```

so that I can jump to the last frame I opened, I added this code

```
if (SOlastFrame.data.lastframe != null) {
    gotoAndStop(SOlastFrame.data.lastframe);
}
```

at **frame 2**, I put dynamic text
with code like this

```
var SOnameUser: SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("saveName");

SOnameUser.data.yourName = shared_data;
SOnameUser.flush();
trace(SOnameUser.data.yourName);

userName.text = "Hello " + shared_data;

if (shared_data != null) {
    userName.text = shared_data;
    SOnameUser.data.yourName = shared_data;
}
```

I think it works, dynamic text is saved successfully.
If I reopen it, it will go directly to frame 2 because of the execution result SOlastFrame.data.lastframe.

the problem is that the username that I saved earlier turns to null.

how can i load dynamic text on shareobject when SOlastFrame.data.lastframe is executed.

or

how to load sharedObject when flash is reopened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it like that because when you start 2-nd time you go straight to the frame 2 where the **shared_data** is empty. I think you should re-organize... well, everything.

```
// Frame 1: Splash (you don't have it).
// First of all, use a single SO rather than two.
var SO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("my.save");

// Check if there are saved fields.
if (SO.data.userName && SO.data.lastFrame)
{
    // If there are saved credentials, the user
    // won't even see the Login Frame.
    gotoAndStop(SO.data.lastFrame);
}
else
{
    // If there are no saved credentials — proceed to the Login Frame.
    nextFrame();
}
```

Then, this is your frame 1.

```
// Frame 2: Login.

stop();

// You don't actually need to SO.flush() every time,
// it's a (feeble) measure against sudden crashes.
SO.data.lastFrame = currentFrame;

// Your code, for the most part, but simpler.
next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNext);

function gotoNext(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // You don't need any additional variables
    // to temporarily store the user name.
    SO.data.userName = inputName.text;
    
    nextFrame();
}
```

Then, here we go.

```
// Frame 3: only logged (via Login Frame or via SO data)
// users reach this point.

stop();

// In case we moved from the Login Frame.
SO.data.lastFrame = currentFrame;

// The only thing left to do.
userName.text = "Hello " + SO.data.userName;
```